# Is it possible to check ABS, ESP and Airbag data from obd port?

Tags: obd-ii

I'm developing an app that read data from car via OBD port.
I'm not expert with this port and i would like to know which type of data i can read from this port.

For sure i can read speed, rpm, coolant temperature,Trouble code and clear it...
I would like to know if it possible to read information from ABS, ESP and Airbag for example.

You know what can i see from this port ?

Comment: What kind of data are you looking for from the airbag? Unless you're planning to drive your car into a collision, there's probably no useful data you can obtain related to airbags.

Comment: You can read data from any module on the network. Assuming you know what you're looking for and have the information to convert it to something readable.

Comment: @juhist whitout collision maybe :D .... i can read Airbag state? Active-not Active ... check if Airbag is ok (like a test if problem occur)

Comment: @Ben I know what i'm looking for and i know how convert information, for example for read rpm i send the command 010C and the car (Elm327) respond with 41 0C 00 00.... the problem is that i don't know the PIDs for commands like exthernal temperature, gasoline level....
I can found them in the Car manual (maybe) ?

Comment: Anything outside of obd2 you need to pay for the info. You may be able to find the info online (think thousands of USD), but that's a big maybe.

Comment: @Ben Info like PID for some sensor?

Comment: yes and all manufactures are different so you have to pay for each.

Comment: I hate this world!
I will try to found some Fiat Forum and try to take some information!

Comment: For VW cars for example, you have to follow a challenge/response authentication before you could even get access to the non-OBD data. (I guess other brands have it similar.)These auth codes are different for each model by purpose so non-syndicated repair shops cannot get the status information from the car. See it as a kind of cartel.

Comment: @Janka i will try in some Italian forum if someone can tell me something about this.

Did you know if the comunication protocol affect the type of pids?
Or only the data transfer?

Comment: The control units will not respond to any non-OBD pids before the service tool has properly authenticated itself. The only thing you can do is wiretapping the normal K-Line/CAN and try to decode what you found out by eavesdropping. You may find some information on this, but it's very specific for each car model and production year.

Comment: Someone in some italian forum tell me to activate the multiecuscan.

@Janka like a sniffer of commands?

Comment: A plain sniffer won't help because it's a challenge-response auth. You cannot just replay something captured. It has to match the new challenge. But you can capture the control units talking to each other.

Comment: Control units? like sensors?
Comunication with sensors and ECU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today i talk with my mechanic and he explain to me how the OBD reader works.

He say:
"You can read and do everything with OBD, like open car, start car etc etc..
But this is not possible with normal PIDs like the list of PIDs in wikipedia but i need specific code that only the mother house of car have"

As other user in this topic say in the comments.

Like Ben say:"Anything outside of obd2 you need to pay for the info. You may be able to find the info online (think thousands of USD), but that's a big maybe."

So with normal usage of OBD port it's possible to read only this commands:

[List of pids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_01)